# android original orientation is ROT_180 ？How android apply screenOrientation reverse?

Tags: android, orientation

I create a app using default project, but on some device,dumpsys surfaceflinger,it shows my app rotated 18：

```
Display 0 HWC layers:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Layer name
           Z |  Window Type |  Comp Type |  Transform |   Disp Frame (LTRB) |          Source Crop (LTRB) |     Frame Rate (Explicit) (Seamlessness) [Focused]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 SurfaceView[cn.dream.artboard/cn.dream.artboard.MainActivity](BLAST)#0
  rel      0 |            0 |     CLIENT |    **ROT_180 **|    0   96 1600 2000 |    0.0    0.0 1600.0 1904.0 |                                              [*]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 cn.dream.artboard/cn.dream.artboard.MainActivity#0
  rel      0 |            1 |     CLIENT |    **ROT_180 **|    0    0 1600 2176 |    0.0    0.0 1600.0 2176.0 |                                              [*]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 StatusBar#0
  rel      0 |         2000 |     DEVICE |          0 |    0 2128 1600 2176 |    0.0    0.0 1600.0   48.0 |                                              [ ]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 NavigationBar0#0
  rel      0 |         2019 |     DEVICE |          0 |    0    0 1600   96 |    0.0    0.0 1600.0   96.0 |                                              [ ]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I tryed to set android:screenOrientation="reversePortrait" in layout.xml, but not work, please help

what can I do to let the layr Orientation become 0 in dumsys SurfaceFlinger ?